# What file formats can be restored using pg_restore on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, restore, psql, pg-restore

first question here, fairly new to DB's and Data itself.

My question is fairly simple, after playing around with Postgres, PGAdmin3, I realised I would like to access some public data, but I struggled to find any publicly available .tar files to practice with. Leading me to wonder what file formats you can restore from.

What file formats can I restore from using pg_restore? And is there a preference in the community towards certain formats?

Thanks for your time. Look forward to participating on the forum.

PS: If it wasn't clear, I am restoring from command line.

Comment: The purpose of `pg_restore` is to restore the formats that `pg_dump` produces. See the `-F` option of [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly one file format is supported by `pg_restore`: the custom PostgreSQL dump formats from `pg_dump -F c` (custom), `-F d` (directory) and `-F t` (tar). Notably it cannot restore `-F s` (SQL) format dumps, which must be passed to `psql -f` instead.

If you want to load data, you probably want the `\copy` command from `psql` or the server-backend `COPY` command. It can load a variety of CSV-like data.

There are also external loader and ETL tools that can do more, e.g. [`pgloader`](http://pgloader.io/), Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, CloverETL, etc.

Comment: According to the help, `pg_restore` can also handle `-F d` ("directory format") and `-F t` ("tar format")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oops, fixed